# How to specify the level for calculating the mode of a multi index series in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, series

I've been using built in pandas methods like on Series such as:

```
 .sum()
 .mean() 
 .median()
```

I noticed in the documentation all of these have an optional level parameter, described in the documentation like so:

```
level : int or level name, default None

If the axis is a MultiIndex (hierarchical), count along a particular level, collapsing into a scalar
```

an example of this for the median method can be found here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.median.html

anyway, i have been using these on multi index series like so:

```
 ser.sum(level=[0, 1, 2]).unstack(2).stack()
 ser.mean(level=[0, 1, 2]).unstack(2).stack()
```

I now have the need to use a mode calculation in the same way as I am using the other calculations on multi index series.

I have tried this:

```
ser.mode(level=[0, 1, 2]).unstack(2).stack()
```

But this tell me level is not an allowed parameter for the mode method and the documentation confirms this:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mode.html

I guess I am curious as to why mode does not have this optional parameter when it's brother/sister methods seem to and more importantly how can I accomplish the functional equivalent of:

```
ser.mode(level=[0, 1, 2]).unstack(2).stack()
```

in pandas?

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't have that parameter but you can use groupby with a custom function `ser.groupby(level=[0, 1, 2]).agg(lambda x: x.mode()[0]).unstack(2).stack()`  (assuming you want the first mode in the case of multiple modes - multiple modes is probably the reason why the level parameter is excluded).

Comment: thanks for the reply @ayhan but sadly the above code snippet gives me an index out of bounds error when i try it :|